# Facebook Messenger bot status to Automated Messaging

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-page, facebook-messenger-bot

I have published my Bot to the Facebook messenger. But my bot shows status as "**Typically Replies Instantly**". How to change that status to "**Automated Messaging**"? Please check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmRux.png) for reference.

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Facebook handles it by itself. You cannot provide the value Automated Messaging. Don't worry though. People are fine with "Typically Replies Instantly". It is the fastest response rate label by the way. As far as I'm aware, at the time of writing, there is no reference to what I just wrote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question that can be answered by simply reading Facebook Messenger documentation and has nothing to do with coding.